# Linux open ports manually and valid reasons to do it

Tags: linux, apache, security, ssh, port

How open a port manually?

I know that if I install apache opens port 80, ssh opens port 22 and that I can change port number in your configuration files.

I was listening to people talk about open ports manually.

How can I make this process? When should I do it?

Thank you.

Comment: Read a good socket programming guide like this http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/index.html

Comment: What do you have in mind exactly when you say "manually"?

Comment: @duskwuff, use any programming language with some api for this, is correct?, but I also think some settings on the server.

Comment: @cmidi, thanks for the reference, after reading ask again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is bit vague. For example you open a port 'manually' if you write some code instructing doing so. By editing a configuration file (like for sshd), you did it 'manually'. You get a bunch of default opened ports by just booting Linux. Do you need all of them? How secure is having these ports opened?

> How can I make this process? , When should I do it?

In simple: You should do it every time you need, like you did on SSH probably for [Security through obscurity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity) or disabling services/programs that you are not using (prevention).
A much better approach than messing around with a bunch of processes (at least at the beginning) is setting up a firewall like iptables, block everything and start discovering what you need or not need to be left opened. 'man nmap' is your friend also.